# Installing Windows 10 app using a link

Tags: deployment, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I have a Windows 8.1 app that I want to be installed on Windows 10 tablet devices. Basically this is an app that the company that I am making app wants for its employees. The following are the conditions that I have

**The employees don't have Azure AD accounts.**

**The customer wants to install the app when the user taps on a link or he can go to the Windows store to install the app**

**The Customer wants a LOB app which can be used Offline**

**He does not wants to make him or the users learn any installation procedure. He just wants everything automatically.**

I have created an Microsoft Business Store account. I don't know how I was able to register an account on the Microsoft Website for free. But I invited myself as Independent Software Vendor and added an offline app to their store. Now I want to make the apps available to the users.
**QUESTIONs:**

*How can I make the above things happen?*

*Do I need to add Users somewhere?*

*How was I able to create a business store by a company's name without any verification?*

I got some options for the offline installation but got very confused with the procedure that is mentioned on MSDN.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried the steps from my answer? does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complicated sideloading with products keys from Windows 8.1 is [removed in Windows 10](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/mt269549.aspx).

In the `Settings App->Update & Security->For Developers` enable the option `Sideload Apps`.

[image]

Now copy the APPX Files of your apps to the device double click/Tab on the appx files and install the apps.